# Single Sign On (SSO) Joomla with other System

Tags: joomla-3.x, login

I've been searching over the net on how to make a Single Sign On Joomla 3.3 to work with a system that is based on Java. Both Joomla portal and java system are under the same server.

I need it to work when:

1. User login using their username and password from frontend joomla portal
2. After login, user can also access the the system without a need to login again

It can happen vice versa as well.

I've got LDAP configured and enabled however still could not get the SSO to work.

Also I have JMapMyLDAP plugin installed and configured and it works well with OpenLDAP. But SSO is not working.

Pretty much in stall now. Is there any idea?

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The are several authentication plugins in Joomla. For instance: **Authentication - LDAP** plugin.

> Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) is a protocol designed to access directory systems over TCP/IP. Because of this various databases provide an LDAP interface such as Microsoft's Active Directory, Novell's eDirectory, as well as more dedicated LDAP solutions such as OpenLDAP.
>
> Joomla! has had a native LDAP library, JLDAP Joomla 2.5 (changed to JClientLDAP in Joomla 3.x) and a native LDAP authentication plugin. This allows Joomla! to authenticate against LDAP systems out of the box: to configure, go to the Plugin Manager and enable and edit the Authentication - LDAP plugin.

**Developer: LDAP from scratch**
http://community.joomla.org/component/zine/article/507-developer-ldap-from-scratch-sam-moffatt.html

[image: Developer: LDAP from scratch]

You can use any of them, or create a new one based on the available source code.

Answer (score 1):

We've never had much luck with Joomla's built-in LDAP support especially for SSO, and with due respect to @Anibal [that community magazine](http://community.joomla.org/component/zine/article/507-developer-ldap-from-scratch-sam-moffatt.html) article is six or seven years out of date and written for Joomla 1.5.4 and AFAIK didn't support SSO at all.

In the past we've used the [JMapMyLDAP Tools](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-cloud-based/18108) for client intranets where they've had everything from OpenLDAP to Active Directory based systems. You can download the plugins from [their website](http://shmanic.com/tools/jmapmyldap/download.htm).

The documentation can be [found here](http://shmanic.com/tools/jmapmyldap/documentation.htm), the [SSO Trouble Shooting page is here](http://shmanic.com/tools/jmapmyldap/documentation/sso-troubleshooting.htm).

**Update:** I found [this article for v1](http://timplummer.com.au/4-how-to-integrate-joomla-3-with-active-directory-using-ldap.html) of [JMapMyLDAP Tools](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-cloud-based/18108) which is at least more recent than the 2007/8 article, albeit about Active Directory.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I have JMapMyLDAP plugin installed. And successfully configure it to work with OpenLDAP. However it doesn't work for SSO.

Comment: Did you check the SSO trouble shooting page? http://shmanic.com/tools/jmapmyldap/documentation/sso-troubleshooting.htm

Comment: Yes I have double check, the problem still remain as I login the portal, my system still display the login page. Do I need to do something with the system? LDAP in there is enable though

Comment: LDAP authentication / basic authentication principles / authentication plugins have not chanced very much since 1.5

Answer (score 0):

For SSO with JMapMyLDAP, once it's enabled in the plugin, make sure your sign-in page on the web server has at least basic authentication enabled.  If your machine is not part of a domain or you don't have NTLM-IWA configured you'll get a a simple username/pass window.

For testing set JMMLDAP to 'force login'.  Then when you login to the basic auth window you'll be automatically logged into the site.

Answer (score -1):

Affiliation Disclosure: **I am affiliated with the below company/product and my recommendation is biased by this fact.**

You could use a [miniOrange](https://plugins.miniorange.com/joomla) plugin.

There are solutions for SAML SSO, OAuth, and LDAP.

You can also search the Joomla Extension Directory (JED) for "miniOrange single sign-on solution".

Comment: This answer was originally deliberately deceptive in that it avoided disclosing the fact that you have a relationship to the company/product and your answer speaks from the perspective of an unbiased user.  I have edited the answer to include disclosure of affiliation.  You must not use Stack Exchange sites to primarily promote your company or product.  If you see a question that can be resolved by using your product, be very clear about your relationship to the product.

Answer (score -2):

Affiliation Disclosure: **I am affiliated with the product/company recommended below.**

If you want to work your flow of LDAP like this:

1. Establishing a session connection. The user establishes a connection to the server using an LDAP port.
   Request.
2. The user sends a query to the server, such as an email lookup.
   Response.
3. The LDAP protocol searches the directory for information and returns it to the user.
4. Completion.

I recommend the solution from miniOrange Inc Joomla's solution from [Joomla LDAP](https://plugins.miniorange.com/joomla-ldap) team. They have multiple plans like for unlimited authentication as well as for Joomla role mapping and attribute mapping also.

You can ask them for a demo for testing the functionalities.

The product is compatible with Joomla 4 and PHP 8.

[Support](https://www.miniorange.com/contact) is also available for customization in your plugin.

Comment: This answer has been flagged by multiple Stack Exchange moderators for being spam due to "undisclosed affiliation ". We don't mind if your answer a question by recommending software from where you work, but you must come clean about your relation to the company/software and the vibe of the post must not be solely to advertise your product/company.