# SSO Login for two joomla websites

Tags: joomla-api, login, access, multi-sites

Can anyone advise on an extension or custom code to sinchronize two joomla 3 websites users access credentials?

I have two sites on the same host and I'd like the users to be able to login in one of them and to be also logged on the other.

Note: Some users have two different access credentials on those sites. ACL must be kept separate.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you done any research in this? There have been lots of people ask the same question all around the web

Comment: Yes, all I could find for joomla is Mighty Sites, and it seems ok although it has a lot of features I don't really need.

Comment: Seems to already be answered: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4820/single-sign-on-sso-joomla-with-other-system

Comment: Here is a role your own option: https://pyd.io/docs/v5/configuring-global-parameters/setup-authentication-driver/todo-enabling-sso-with-a-php-based-cms-drupal-joomla-wordpress-your-own/

Comment: I tried both extensions but I couldn't understand how they allow me to connect users of both sites. In LDAP extension, after installing all those plugins and reading the instructions nothing seems to have change in the site. With Pydio, they say I need a bridge to Joomla, but where is it?

Comment: And uninstalling LDAP? It broke the site!